# Find no of repeated characters in a string using one for loop with no variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was asked an interview question for a Python developer position. All went well but there was one question I couldn't answer - the question was:

Find the number of characters repeated in a string with the following restrictions:

1. You are allowed one for loop or while loop only.
2. No new variable can be defined with a list, dictionary or any such thing that will consume memory.

Alphabets in a string can be in any sequence.

Example:

x="ABCDEAB"

Solution:

AB

Output can be delivered in any format but the characters need to be identified.

Comment: what have you tried so far? without any new variable how can you keep track of the count?

Comment: show your initial code

Comment: This can be done easily if you sort the string...yes?

Comment: Try checking `set` function and what it does.

Comment: @Anwarvic not really, repetitive characters mean characters that are next to each other. If a character are on the same string but not on succeeding positions, it is not repetitive. You cannot use sorting.

Comment: @komatiraju032  I couldn't start since I don't know what is the solution

Comment: can you add an example and expected output

Comment: @komatiraju032 I just did

Comment: I think the example is incorrect. There's no repetitive character in `ABCDEAB`. Repetitive means 2 or more succeeding characters.

Comment: what i mean is which characters are repeated in a string that need to be identified

Comment: @RonieMartinez AB is repeated

Comment: Are you looking for repeated substring or characters? ["A", "B"] or ["AB"]?

Comment: @RonieMartinez characters

Comment: as @anwarvic said you can do it by sorting the string

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed the [tag:python-2.7) tag.

Comment: @Anwarvic with sorting I will have to sort first and then loop to check duplicate but the problem is sorting itself loops internally so I cannot loop second time

Comment: @vibhorGupta internal implementation details of the language should not be considered. Coding exams will only consider your code implementation. `sort()` and `count()` are acceptable features.

Comment: Actualy any string slicing or `in` operator are looping internally, hencefore we can't disqualify sort that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one follows both the rules

```
x='ABCDEAB'
for i in x:
   try:
       if(i in x[x.index(i)+1:]):
           print(i,end=" ")
           x=x.replace(i,"",1)
   except ValueError:
       pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sample_string = "ABCDEAB"

for index in range(len(sample_string)):
    if sample_string[index] in sample_string[index + 1 :]:
        print(sample_string[index], end="")
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution that I was looking out for....Thank you Vishal

Comment: If I try with `s = "PPPPPPABCABCABCDEABFGHABCSSS"` I would expect to get the answer "ABCABC", but the above code returns "PPPPPABCABCABCABSS". Or maybe I'm answering to another question (longest repeated substring).

Comment: OK, I understand: the problem statement is ambiguous and I interpreted it in a different way (see my answer for details).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I was able to sketch in Java, you can try the same logic in python I guess:

```
/*
 * Rules:
 * 1. i should not be greater then str.lenght()-1
 * 2. j should be greater then i
 * 3. if str.charAt[i] == str.charAt[j] then reset j to str.lenght()-1 and increment i
 * 4. if str.charAt[i] == str.charAt[j] then decrement j but no change to i
 * 5. if j <= i then increment i and set j to str.lenght()
 */
public void algorithm(String str) {
    for(Integer i=0, j=str.length()-1; i < str.length() && j > i; i++, j--) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
            System.out.println(str.charAt(i)+" Char Matched");
            j = str.length();
        }
        else {
            i--;
            if (j-1 <= i+1) {
                i++;
                j = str.length();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

word = "ABCDEAB"

print([k for k, v in Counter(word).items() if v > 1])  # ['A', 'B']
```

Use a list comprehension:

```
word = "ABCDEAB"

print([k for k in set(word) if word.count(k) > 1])
```

EDIT: If comprehensions are a problem, then print immediately:

```
word = "ABCDEAB"

for k in set(word):
  if word.count(k) > 1:
    print(k)
```

Comment: did your answer satisfy the second condition?

Comment: I think so. You cannot use a for loop if you do not use variable/s in the for loop (satisfies #1) or else both requirements will clash.

Comment: You exactly copied my earlier answer in your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the question should be answered, as at first reading I understood it as "Find the length of the longest repeated substring" instead of "Find the number of Characters appearing more than once". Both questions match the proposed sample answer.

I t appears that the consensus of the answers if about finding characters appearing more than once, but for fun I will answer to the other possible question, also taking into account imposed constraints.

Hencefore let's cheat! If we remove the constraint on loops the search of the longest substring is easy using a brute force algorithm like below:

```
# Find the largest common subsequence in string

s = "PPPPPPABCABCABCDEABFGHABCSSS"

class Found(BaseException): pass

try:
    for n in range(len(s)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(0,len(s)-n):
            for j in range(i+1, len(s)-n):
                if s[i:i+n] == s[j:j+n]:
                    print("Found:", i, j, n, s[i:i+n], s[j:j+n])
                    raise Found;
except Found:
    pass
```

What is fun is that it is also trivial to change the above code so that it uses only one external loop rather than 3 embedded loops.

```
try:
    n, i, j = len(s) - 1, 0, 1
    while n > 0:
        if i == len(s)-n - 1:
            n, i, j = n - 1, 0, 1
            continue

        if j == len(s) - n - 1:
            i,j = i + 1, i + 2
            continue

        if s[i:i+n] == s[j:j+n]:
            print("Found:", i, j, n, s[i:i+n], s[j:j+n])
            raise Found;

        j = j + 1

except Found:
    pass
```

You can notice I left the string comparison wich is still actually an hidden loop. It wouldn't be much harder to also remove that loop using the same loop rewriting pattern as above.

Answer (score 0):

As nobody else did it, and even if it's not very Pythonic, I'm proposing a solution using recursion. It should qualify for the "no loop" requirement, and also uses no variable at all beside the input string (of course there is some hidden stack space used anyway)

```
# Count Characters Appearing more than once in String

def nbdup(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return 0
    if s.count(s[0]) == 2:
        print(s[0])
        return 1 + nbdup(s[1:])
    return nbdup(s[1:])

print(nbdup("ABCDEAB"))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is only one for loop, but it's not very efficient...

```
x = "ABCDEAB"
[c for c in set(x) if x.count(c) > 1]
```

Output:

```
['B', 'A']
```

Note that requirement 1 implies that a loop variable is allowed and requirement 2 is satisfied because I never assign a list or dict to a name.

Comment: but doesn't count uses loop internally?

Comment: @vibhorGupta the implementation details should not be considered.